# Какой глагол подходит? Значение слова "сгоревший"

Tags: семантика

Какой глагол подходит? Например: «Сгоревший мотылёк упал? лёг?»

Какие глаголы подойдут? Что может делать (сделать) сгоревший мотылёк?

Comment: И сгоревший падает и обожжённый. Вероятно, вам хочется показать: остался жив либо погиб мотылёк?

Comment: Сгоревший мотылёк упал, погиб. Хочу уточнить, правильно ли это, ведь сгоревший мотылёк - уже пепел, а не мотылёк.  Что упало?

Comment: Упал мертвым, упал пеплом - так и используйте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мотылек сгорел, то вниз он падает уже в виде пепла, праха, хлопьев, пыли, искр или угольков (c "сопровождающими" определениями: мерцающий, горячий, светящийся, тлеющий...).

Контекста нет, поэтому можно только предполагать.
Вот возможные глаголы, описывающие процесс падения останков мотылька:
пал, свегся (свергнулся), низвергся, повергся, повалился, ухнул, рухнул, опустился, ссыпался, осыпался; поплыл, полетел, понесся, разнесся (на ветру).

Сгоревший мотылек светящимися хлопьями опустился на траву.
Мотылек, обданный огнем, вспыхнул и осыпался на землю мерцающей пылью.

Answer (score 1):

Опалённый огнём...

Над заревом, точно опаленные огнем пожара, потухали светлячки звезд и таяла побледневшая луна. [А. П. Гайдар. Школа (1929)]

*Вбегает весь опаленный огнем шут Экко и судорожно мечется по зале; за ним с криком гонятся слуги.* [Л. Н. Андреев. Чёрные маски. Представление в двух действиях и пяти картинах (1908)]

Comment: Опаленный огнём, сгоревший мотылёк, что он может делать? Падать? Какие глаголы подойдут?

Comment: Парить, опуститься, спланировать, оказаться (внизу).